# calling an object inside a service

Tags: angularjs

I have set a condition in my service so that,only that data is called every-time. But the data I get in callback is in array and I want it to be in object. So how do it get it as an object in callback and send it to the controller.

```
var _getSettings = function (callback) {
    $http.get('localhost:8081/app/getSettings')
        .success(function (data,response) {
            if (data.length>0) {
                callback(data);
            }
        }).error(function (data,error) {
            if (callback) {
                callback(null, data);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you share what kind of array you are getting , and what object structure looks like ?

Comment: Currently my callback(data) looks like `[{name:"john",age:23,work:"technical"}]` but I want it to be `{name:"john",age:23,work:"technical"}`

Comment: just do `return data[0]`

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak Can I use  something like this ` data[index]`, Is it correct way ??

Comment: @user7397693 correct, you can get first element your element by that way

Comment: @user7397693 did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Return the `$http` promise and handle it at your controller:

Service:

```
var _getSettings = function () {
    return $http.get('localhost:8081/app/getSettings');
}
```

Controller:

```
_getSettings()
  .success(function(data, response) {
    if (data.length > 0) {
      callback(data[0]); // return data[0]
    }
  })
  .error(function(data, error) {
    if (callback) {
      callback(null, data);
    }
  });
```

Comment: This is much cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
var _getSettings = function (callback) {
    $http.get('localhost:8081/app/getSettings')
        .success(function (data,response) {
          var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            if (obj.length>0) {
                callback(obj);
            }
        }).error(function (data,error) {
            if (callback) {
                callback(null, data);
            }
        });
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)` . I'm getting syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Handle the function calling part into the controller itself. Just get the promise from the API in the controller through a service `httpCall`.

**Service :**

```
app.service('httpCall', [
    '$http',
    '$q',
    'storageService',
    '$location',
    function(
        $http,
        $q,
        storageService,
        $location
    ) {

        this.callAPI = function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            var url = 'localhost:8081/app/getSettings';
            var method = 'GET';
            var params = {};
            var data = {};

            $http({
                    url: url,
                    method: method,
                    params: params,
                    data: data
                })
                .then(function successCallback(response) {
                    deferred.resolve(response);
                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    deferred.reject(response);
                });

            return deferred.promise;
        };

    }
]);
```

**Controller :**

Inject `httpCall` in the controller.

```
app.controller('myCtrl',function(httpCall) {
httpCall.callAPI()
    .then(function(res) {
        if (res.data.length>0) {
            callback(data);
        }                   
    }, function(err) {
        if (callback) {
            callback(null, data);
        }
    });                                                                                                                      
});
```